# How to get out pulsed output with BJT?

Tags: bjt

Is there any process of getting pulse output with BJT? The input must be plain DC. Is there any process existing?

I tried to make pulsed output. It is very easy to make with micro-controller. But I want to get it with BJT. I recently try some circuits. Astable Multivariator is one of them. But I can't understand its operation.

I need a circuit design with working procedure with BJT that can make pulsed output. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of 'pulse generating circuits' that can be built using BJTs. A very common one is the astable multi-vibrator. A little bit of research on your part would have produced lots of answers.

[image]

You change the frequency of the pulses by changing the values of R2, R3, C1 and C2.